# Get Blob Content from bindings and then zip the content and save it in the blob container using azure function

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-functions, azureportal, jszip

I am using bindings of azure function to get the blob content and to store the file in blob.
Below is the code that I am using but its not passing anything to the output bindings.

```
const JSZip = require("jszip");
const saveas = require('file-saver')
module.exports = async function (context, myBlob) {
    context.log("Function Triggered. ", context.bindingData.blobTrigger);
        
 var input = context.bindings.myBlob;
     var inputBuffer = Buffer.from(input);
     var zip = new JSZip();
zip.file(inputBuffer);
zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
.then(function(content) {

 var j =   saveAs(content, "example.zip");
  context.bindings.myOutputBlob = j; 
});
 
 
 
 }
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the output binding in such a way to give a container name and a new blob name where you can input your content in it. And your code looks fine.

Also you can setup perfect bindings from VS Code just with few clicks according to your requirement.

Below is the sample input and output binding:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "queueName": "myqueue-items",
      "connection": "MyStorageConnectionAppSetting",
      "name": "myQueueItem",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "name": "myInputBlob",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "samples-workitems/{queueTrigger}",
      "connection": "MyStorageConnectionAppSetting",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "name": "myOutputBlob",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "samples-workitems/{queueTrigger}-Copy",
      "connection": "MyStorageConnectionAppSetting",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Please refer to [supported bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings?tabs=csharp)

Comment: My output bindings is creating a new file when I am just compressing the file using zlib but when I am using jszip to zip my file, the output binding is not creating anything. Can you please let me know how to create a zip a file and pass it to the output bindings. It seems the zip file is somehow not being sent over to the output bindings